# Remaining budget in Adwords Api

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I would like an aid to get an Adwords information through the API.
I would like to take the Remaining budget, Account budget and Spent but I am not having success in catching in the API.

Could tell me how to get this information?

[image]

Comment: Can't flag this question but it duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638938/remaining-adwords-account-budget-using-api