# Remaining AdWords account budget (using API)

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I am searching for a way to extract data using AdWords API.
Particularly, I need to get remaining AdWords account budget.

Please, let me know how can I get remaining account budget using AdWords API.

Comment: [Quote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/kQyyzdJ9_Qs): The BudgetOrderService will not return the account budget, remaining amount or % spent. But you will be able to calculate these values.
The account budget will be equal to `spendingLimit - totalAdjustments`.
The remaining amount can be found out once you know the spend. To find out spend, you could save the `spendingLimit` locally and apply the calculation as : `spent = (oldSpendingLimit - newSpendingLimit) + totalAdjustments`. 
Once you know the spend you will be able to calculate the remaining amount and % spent.

Comment: I've been monitoring this topic for years, and Google still keeps ignoring all requests about it. They suggest using ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT to calculate the cost and then subtract it from `spendingLimit`, but this method appears to be totally inaccurate and gives numbers very different from those shown in AdWords. I've ended up using direct GWT requests (as AdWords web interface does), which is undocumented (and usually needs fixing after Google changes anything on servers), but at least it gives the correct numbers.